# Best way to conditionally load a stylesheet in all versions of IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I am working on a site where I need to load a conditional stylesheet for every version of IE(up to 11). I realize that conditional comments are not supported in IE10+ so I will need another way of conditionally loading this stylesheet. The other thing is that I do not want this stylesheet to load on Microsoft Edge, only on Internet Explorer.

What would be the best way to go about this?

To clarify, I am attempting to target all versions of IE, not just 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are There Specific CSS Selectors Targeting IE10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321093/are-there-specific-css-selectors-targeting-ie10)

Comment: That is not a duplicate, I am attempting to target ALL versions of IE, not just 10.

Comment: You can use CSS Hacks,  take a look [here](http://browserhacks.com/#ie)

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional comments up to and with ie9, you can use conditional compilation for ie10, as for ie11 and edge, ua sniff is the route i would go, knowing full well its not a solid approach and will inevitably break something.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using PHP to add a class to the body if the user was using IE since it uses the least amount of code:

```
if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false))
```

[Source](http://ageekandhisblog.com/use-php-to-detect-internet-explorer-11-and-below/)